# What is the maximum range of a type 2 phaser?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, weapon

I was checking [memory alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phaser) and was not able to determine the maximum range of a handheld 'type 2' phaser. What is the canon based answer regarding how far a class 2 hand phaser can be effectively used? [image: Phaser]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from the memory alpha article on [phasers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phaser)

> The Star Fleet Technical Manual gives the effective ranges for different settings. On the type 1 phaser they were: stun - thirty meters, heat - two meters, disrupt - twenty meters, dematerialization - ten meters. **On the type 2 phaser the ranges were: stun - ninety meters, heat - six meters, disrupt - sixty meters, dematerialization - thirty meters.**